# external javascript file not working on blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, addthis

i am using add this tool box on my blog. But i want to optimize my blog so i decided to host that add this javascript file from google drive. But when i hosted the file then javascript is not working. But when i try to use javascript file from add this it works. I have tried hosting another javascript file from google drive for other page on my blog and it worked. Tell me how can i fix it, because i copied the entire javascript code from the add this javascript file.

And i put a script source tag as follows.

https://googledrive.com/host/0BxeU3LVwPHLPUldPSUpLOGtzYUk' type='text/javascript'/>

the file in google drive is at this link 
https://googledrive.com/host/0BxeU3LVwPHLPUldPSUpLOGtzYUk

The original javascript from addthis is available at the link below
//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-513959962cb3b4b6

currently i am using the original external javascript file from add this, so the like box is showing. And in case you need my site url it is below :

http://techtrickzone.blogspot.in/

How can i get the javascript file from google drive working ??

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for contacting AddThis support.

I am AddThis support agent Elsa. Unfortunately, we do not recommend copying addthis_widget.js into any other location since we update that file fairly often with fixes/updates. If you copy it, you would be stuck on an older version and you wouldn't get updates. If it makes you feel any better, our assets are highly cached, so they really shouldn't add too much load for your users since all the js/css files are probably already available on their browser.

Feel free to contact us for more questions.

Thanks,

Elsa.

Comment: sorry , but when i checked my page for page speed, i came to know hat the javascript from add this is taking a lot of time to load. At the same time i want to ask you that even though if i host your js file from other location then i will not receive updates- ok , but atleast i should be able to use the older version of add this, so why isn't it working ?